# Conditioning tri-state logic

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I have a variable that takes a value out of tri-state booleans:

```
asap = true
asap = false
asap = nil
```

Ruby's conditionals interpret them as truthy or falsey. Especially, `nil` is not distinguished from `false`.

```
asap = nil
unless asap
  puts 'False'
end
# => 'False'
```

A statement that distinguishes `false` from `nil` is:

```
if asap == false
  puts 'False'
end
```

but RubyMine 6.3.3 complains that the expression could be simplified, and suggests `unless asap`. Is there  a different (right) way to do the conditioning?

Comment: Blame RubyMine. It is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDNR;**

```
if FalseClass === asap
  puts 'False'
end
```

---

Tri-state usually suggests that there are three possible branches, which forces me to think that neither `if` nor ternary `?` is generally applicable.

```
puts case asap
     when FalseClass then 'False' 
     when TrueClass then 'True' 
     when NilClass then 'Nil' 
     else 'You are kidding on me, aren’t you?'
     end
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD:** The more I think about it, the more I am inclined to think that ternary is fine as well:

```
puts asap.nil? ? 'Nil' : asap ? 'True' : 'False'
```

**UPD2:** Actually, the tri-equal comparision operator, which is transparently used in `case` and which apparently evaluates to `true` for `false === false` and `true === true` might satisfy IDEA aka RubyMine as well:

```
if asap === false
  puts 'False'
end
```

**UPD3**: As @sawa mentioned in the comment, IDEA is wrong here since `nil == false` evaluates to `false` and therefore `== false` is not generally equal to `unless`.

Comment: Your use of `case` statement is right, but I see your code inconsistent. If you have `false` and `true`, then why not have `nil` instead of `NilClass`? Or to put it the other way, if you are using `NilClass`, then why aren't you using `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`?

Comment: @sawa You are right; I wanted to show different approaches but as a result I simply messed the things up. Updated.

Comment: Your idea with `case` works when all the possible variable values are consumed in one place. My case is different: each single state is being checked in many places of the app and different states are checked in different places.